# Make angular controller run every time I'm loading a view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, controller

I'm having difficulty solving this problem. I have for instance, a set of items I can add to a shopping cart. Then I can edit these Items, so I have a controller and a view for each type of item. Inside this controller I'm doing something like `$scope.item=$scope.$parent.item;` The problem is that if I have 2 of the same items the controller only runs once if I click between them, thus not updating the `$scope.item`.

How do I make it run every time I click on the item?

*EDIT*
I'm using ng-include for adding the view, and using  `<div ng-controller="ItemCtrl">` Can that be the case? I guess since it is the same template in `ng-include` the view doesn't reload and the controller doesn't re init.

Comment: Hi, can you post the full code or a plunker?

Comment: you can add a watch on both the items and update the other.